# Требуется ли запятая в предложении?

Tags: пунктуация

С каждым упущенным просмотром мы теряем одного потенциального конкурента.

Answer (score 1):

***С каждым упущенным просмотром //мы теряем одного потенциального конкурента.***

Это простое неосложненное предложение. Обстоятельственный оборот входит в основное содержание предложения и не обособляется.

После оборота делается небольшая произносительная пауза, но такие паузы запятой не обозначаются. (В простом предложении пауза также обозначает перелом интонации: повышение тона - понижение тона).

В общем случае обособление обстоятельственных оборотов является факультативным и зависит от ряда факторов.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=114#pp114